# How do I insert a list of pairs most efficiently?

Tags: c++, containers

Supose i have

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(A,D)
(B,C)
(B,D)
(C,D)
(D,E)
```

in a text file.  I'll extract it using regular expressions.

I would like to insert the data in to a container so that it looks like this.

```
A->B,C,D
B->C,D
C->D
D->E
```

Which container do I use?

I need to be able to look up data on both the left hand and right hand side of the container, i.e. by key an value.  So I need to be able to search/lookup

A,B,C,D in

```
A->B,C
B->C,D
C->D
D->E
```

and the B,C in

```
A->B,C
```

Comment: How does `(A,D)` fit into your expected data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[std::multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) comes to mind... Is basically a map, but allows duplicates in the map key (i.e. you can have multiple "A" keys, each mapping to a "B", "C" or "D" key, to continue your example).

**EDIT:** In response to Chris' comment: you insert items into a multimap in the same manner as a map - you make a `std::pair` object containing the key and value, then [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/insert/) that into the multimap:

```
std::multimap<char, char> myMap;
myMap.insert(std::pair<char, char>('A', 'B'));
myMap.insert(std::pair<char, char>('A', 'C'));
myMap.insert(std::pair<char, char>('A', 'D'));
myMap.insert(std::pair<char, char>('B', 'C'));
// ... etc
```

Assuming here that you literally are examining characters, and `A`, `B`, `C` etc aren't stand-ins for something else. If they are stand-ins, adjust as appropriate.

You can then query the multimap for all values under the key 'A' as follows:

```
typedef std::multimap<char, char>::iterator mmIter; // For brevity...
std::pair<mmIter, mmIter> iters = myMap.equal_range('A');
// Iterate over values for key
for (mmIter iter = iters.first ; iter != iters.second; ++iter)
{
    // Print out value.
    cout << " " << (*iter).second;
}
```

[`multimap.equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/) returns a `pair` containing iterators to the first entry matching the key, and the entry immediately following the last entry matching the key. Therefore, these can be used to iterate over the entries, as demonstrated.

**EDIT 2** just realised what you really meant by your comment. Multimap does not natively support bidirectional operation (i.e. lookup on value as well as on key), so you might then need to maintain *two* multimaps - one for each direction. This can be a pain to do though - it can be tricky ensuring that the two remain properly synchronised.

Alternatively, I'm sure there's some [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) class that would serve the purpose (I don't actually know - I don't use Boost myself, but I'm sure someone else should be able to provide more detail).

Comment: I need to to do lookups and insert on both the key and the elements

Comment: You're specifically looking for Boost::MultiIndex -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: Probably [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) is the answer, it's an evolute version of the MultiIndex and offers an incredible flexibility in mapping elements of a collection to another.

Comment: @Matteo: Bimap does not allow multiple values per key.

Comment: @Billy: Probably you're right, but I read in the introduction that "It is possible to control the collection type of each side of the relationship that the bimap represents, giving *one-to-many containers* ", and I was trying right now to understand how is this achieved.

Comment: Decided to go with a map of sets.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have to lookup the data on the righthand side using the 'key' on the lefthand side, I'd use a multimap to store these values.

The other alternative would be something like a `std::map<keytype, std::vector<valuetype> >`.

Comment: I need to to do lookups and insert on both the key and the elements